# gstreamer pipeline only generates mono stream

Tags: gstreamer, gst-launch

I'm trying to get UPNP streaming to work. [Rygel](https://live.gnome.org/Rygel%E2%80%8E) runs fine, however, all I get is a mono stream, even if the input is stereo. Doing some debugging, I replicated Rygel's gstreamer pipeline with

```
gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc device=upnp.monitor num-buffers=100 ! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc target=quality quality=6 ! filesink location=test.mp3
```

where the problem is also apparent:

```
mp3info -x test.mp3
...
Media Type:  MPEG 1.0 Layer III
Audio:       Variable kbps, 44 kHz (mono)
...
```

Where does this pipeline lose the second channel? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

You never ask for stereo:

```
gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc device=upnp.monitor num-buffers=100 ! "audio/x-raw,channels=2" ! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc target=quality quality=6 ! filesink location=test.mp3
```

Comment: Nice ! It is working in Rygel after removing quotes : pulsesrc device=upnp.monitor ! audio/x-raw,channels=2 ! lamemp3enc target=quality quality=6

Answer (score 0):

Add a -v to the launch-line to see all the caps negotiated on all pads of the pipeline. Look for "channels" and see where it goes from 2 to 1.